# How to create a slash command with spacing in the name?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I've seen some bots that have space in the name of their slash commands, ex: `/admin ban`

[image: afk on command along with afk off command]

But when I try to implement it, I get an error saying that the name of the slash command does not match a validation regex.

**My code:**

```js
guild.commands.create({
    name: 'foo bar',
    description: 'random description here'
});
```

**Error:**

```
DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
name: String value did not match validation regex.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are called [subcommands](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/application-commands#subcommands-and-subcommand-groups). They are a good way to sort commands. For example, instead of using `setsomething` and `deletesomething` commands, you could use `something delete` and `something set`.

You can do this with the `options` property, and setting the type to `SUB_COMMAND`

```js
guild.commands.create({
  name: "foo",
  description: "random description here",
  options: [
    {
      type: "SUB_COMMAND",
      name: "bar",
      description: "some description"
    }
  ]
})
```

You can get this in the `interactionCreate` event through `.getSubcommand()`

```js
const subcommand = interaction.options.getSubcommand() // "bar"
```